# How do I limit the number of nodes posted by a user to an entity referenced node?

Tags: nodes, users

I have created a content type (*Reviews*). I am referencing another content type (*Books*) using the Entity Reference module. How do I limit the number of reviews posted per book to 1 per user? Is there a module for this?

I have already experimented with the node_limit module but that doesn't work in this particular context. It restricts the user from posting content per content-type but not per node.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers.

Comment: I believe field validation has such a feature https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the the [Unique Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_field) module

> This module performs additional validation when a node is created or updated by a user to require that a node's title, author, language, and CCK fields are unique within a given context.

This might help you.

Comment: How, exactly? I mean, I would need unique not on field, but on a field in a node referenced from a field...

Comment: using unique you can limit a user to review only once

Comment: You already said that, but you didn't explain *how*.

Comment: I haven't used This module but i am sure you can link it through reference...

Comment: I *am using it* in few projects and I can't see how it could help here.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a module for that ("yet", may be). However, this can be done easily with a form alter hook and validation.

```
<?php 
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#node']->type == 'article') {
    $validate = TRUE;
  }
  // You can also use field existence like following:
  if (isset($form['field_name_that_you_want_to_validate'])) {
    $validate = TRUE;
  }

  if (!empty($validate = TRUE;)) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_node_validate_only_one_review';
    form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'MYMODULE', 'FILE_THAT_CONTAINS_THE_VALIDATE_FUNCTION');
  }
}
?>
```

Then, define the validate function:

```
<?php 
function MYMODULE_node_validate_only_one_review($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!empty($form_state['field_name_that_you_want_to_validate'])) {
    $nids = array();
    foreach ($form_state['field_name_that_you_want_to_validate'] as $language => $items) {
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        if (!empty($item['target_id'])) {
          $nids[$item['target_id']] = array($language, $delta);
        }
      }
    }
    if (!empty($nids)) {
      $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
      $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
        ->propertyCondition('uid', $GLOBALS['user']->uid)
        ->fieldCondition('field_name_that_you_want_to_validate', 'target_id', $nids);

      $matches = $query->execute();
      if (isset($matches['node'])) {
        foreach ($nids as $nid => $pack) {
          if (isset($matches['node'][$nid])) {
            list($language, $delta) = $pack;
            form_set_error('field_name_that_you_want_to_validate][' . $language . '][' . $delta, 
              t('You have already submitted a review for this content.');
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

**There are 4 assumptions:**

- Node type is `article`. Change all instances of `article` with the correct node type machine name.
- Your field name is `field_name_that_you_want_to_validate`. Change it accordingly.
- You are using Entity Reference module for node reference (hence, the `target_id` key. It would be `nid` if you use References module)
- This bounty gave you the hat ;)

**There is 1 fact:**

- I submitted this answer for the hat.

**There is 1 hope:**

- I will get that hat.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers approach the requirement from a validation standpoint. I think it's better from a user experience standpoint (and I think it makes more sense logically) to tackle it earlier - at presentation. That is, don't present the option to review a book if the user has already reviewed it. Only show books that *can be reviewed* by the acting user when giving them the list of books to select for reviewed.

**Summarized approach**:

> Upon creation of a Book Review, limit the list of books available for review to those that have not previously been reviewed by the reviewer.

Given this approach, we want to limit the list of books a user can select when creating a review to those that have not previously been reviewed by the reviewer. Entity Reference allows you to use a View to generate the list of reference-able entities. **So all you need is a view that displays all Books that haven't been referenced by the current user yet.**

More simple (given that we're already excluding entities that aren't books): **Show me all books, but exclude books that have been referenced by this user already.**

**Basic instructions:**

1. **Create a new view**. It will need a display type of "Entity Reference". But for now, I suggest giving it a Page display so you can test.
2. **Join the referenc*ed* and referenc*ing* entities**: Add a reference to `Entity Reference: Referencing` entity (note Referenc**ing**, not Referenc**ed**)
3. **Only return Articles** - Under filter criteria, create a filter for `Content Type = Article`
4. **Filter based on user** - Under Contextual Filters, create a Contextual Filter for `Content: Author uid:`

   1. **When the filter value is *not* in the URL**: Provide default value = User ID from logged in user
   2. **Negate the expression** - Under "More", select "Exclude" (Exclude essentially negates the filter [and might be inappropriately misnamed as such] - we want to return all referenced nodes that *weren't* created by the current user).
5. **Verify, add view display, and profit** - At this point you should be able to visit the URL of the view you created as different users. There you can verify that the only Book nodes that are displayed are those that have not been reviewed by the current user (or those not reviewed at all). Once you've tested and verified it's working, add a display to the view of type "Entity Reference". Then back in your Review content type, set the Entity Reference field's Mode to "Views" and select the view you just created.

Comment: This is both creative and a practical approach. +1, even if I have my own question here.

Comment: Thanks @AyeshK  I think the next steps are clear. Given **A)** You want hats **B)** My answer is *great* **C)** There is a hat for deleting your own answer **D**) I want hats too. ;)

Comment: If it wasn't without your *:;* emoticon, I find your comment threatning :D OP will choose a bounty winner on his own. I already have the *Fear & loading* hat. I dedicated a lot to be the #1 in DA winterbash.

Comment: @AyeshK it will not be the OP who will award that bounty, I will, as I founded it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node Review](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodereview) module for review functionality to nodes.

I you want it in the way you are using then I think you need to use `hook_node_validate` to validate node before saving.

```
function hook_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  if ($node->type == 'review') {
    // check if review node exists for the selected referenced field value display for same uid.
  }
}
```